# How to avoid the exception "Invalid hex characters in a String"

Tags: javascript, rhino

I'm using Javascript and Rhino (to do some Java codes). I want to execute the following code.

```
service.push(deviceToken,payload);
```

As the first string contains 'x' it gives the following exception.

com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid hex character: x

That string has to be there as it is. Therefore no replaces are possible.

I'm using Java-apns and I use this method to push notifications with the device token and the payload.

Comment: As it stands your question is too localized... Also please consider your title "eliminate ... characters in a String" and requirement in the body "string has to be there as it is" which makes your question very confusing.

Comment: that string contains characters that cannot be change by the program (like password). When I Google this error I got an answer like replacing those hex characters with "" or any other characters. But in this scenario that is not possible. I,m looking forward to a method that avoid checking those hex characters in a String.

Comment: A full stack trace will tell you the class the RuntimeException originated in.  I doubt it is a Rhino class. There is not enough information here to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your device token should contain only hexadecimal characters 0–9 , A, B, C, D, E, F (or alternatively a–f)